# Copy and paste specific cell values

Tags: vba, excel

When I run the program, nothing happens. I think it's because I am not using the right variable types or I am not doing variable and value assignment properly.

This is what I want the code to do:

For every cell from *row 80, column 6* to *row 90, column 6*, I want `j` to be the INTEGER specified in that cell. For every column from 10 to 100, if the DATE in `Cells(i,2)` is the same as the DATE in `Cells(1,k)`, then I want to set `Cells(j, k)` as the INTEGER found in `Cells(j, 6)`.

Please help me correct this code.

```
    Sub TestSub()

Dim i As Integer, i2 As Integer, i3 As Integer
Dim j As Integer, j2 As Integer, j3 As Integer
Dim k As Integer, k2 As Integer, k3 As Integer

For i = 81 To 95

    j = Cells(i, 6) 'j becomes the row # of the equipment

    For k = 8 To k = 115
        If Cells(i, 2) = Cells(1, k) Then Cells(j, k) = Cells(j, 6) 'Cells(i,2)->NEXT PM DATE Cells(1,k)->CALENDER DATE (MM/1/YY)
    Next k

Next i


For i2 = 97 To 105

    j2 = Cells(i2, 6)

    For k2 = 8 To k2 = 115
        If Cells(i2, 2) = Cells(1, k2) Then Cells(j2 + 1, k2) = Cells(j2 + 1, 6)
    Next k2

Next i2


For i3 = 107 To 121

j3 = Cells(i3, 6)

    For k3 = 8 To k3 = 115
         If Cells(i3, k3) = Cells(j3, 6) Then Cells(j3 + 2, k3) = Cells(j3 + 2, 6)
    Next k3

Next i3

End Sub
```

Comment: Ok I changed it but it doesn't fix my problem, what about the other possible problems i mentioned?

Comment: Is the `Cells(1, k)` intentional? You refer to `Cells(i, k)` in your narrative.

Comment: yes it is intentional, i just referred to Cells(i,k) in my narrative to communicate my understanding of Cells

Comment: Your description doesn't correspond to your code. It seems that you mixed up the i and j indices. You assign a value to a cell whose address is determined by the content of `cells(i,6)` - ???

Comment: I have re-edited the description to further clarify what i want the code to do, anyone have any idea why nothing is happening when i run this code?

Comment: Are we working with dates or integers? Right now you have declared i & j as variants. So if B80=F80 then what?

Comment: i, j, and k are all supposed to be integers. sorry for confusion. i edited the code so they are all declared as integers.

Comment: would you please post the values for the range `F80:F90`

Comment: It might help if you complete this.
`if B80=F80 then.......`

Comment: values for range F80:F90 ->
73
71
76
18
22
25
40
32
62
53
45

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to post a second answer as the asker changed entirely the code:

These lines will never work

`For k = 8 To k = 115`

`For k2 = 8 To k2 = 115`

`For k3 = 8 To k3 = 115`

Change to the correct format

`For k = 8 To 115`

`For k2 = 8 To 115`

`For k3 = 8 To 115`

Then try

Comment: Amen. Glad it worked, however noticed that your first post omitted the problem as you did not posted the actual code you were using. Please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what your code is doing:

It compares the dates for each cell in range `B80:B90` *(rows 80 to 90)* with the dates of cells in range `J1:CV1` *(columns 10 to 100)*
If the dates compared are equal then it takes the value in the same row and column 6 (`F`). This value is then used to reference a row number and places that row number in the column that contains the same date.

The program is validating the dates in range `B80:B90` with the dates in range `J1:CV1` and for those found equal is updating the corresponding cell in the row  determined by the corresponding value in the range `F80:F90`.

Let’s look at the following sample case, where the date in cell `B80` equals the date in cell `J1` and the value in cell `F80` is `97`.
Then the program will enter the value of cell `F97` in cell `J97`

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    For i = 80 To 90
        If i = 89 Then Stop
        j = Cells(i, 6)
            For k = 10 To 100

'as per the sample case
'i = 80 ; j = 97 and k = 10
'date in cell(B80) = date in cell(J1)
                'If Cells(i, 2) = Cells(1, k) Then Cells(j, k) = Cells(j, 6) 
'then J97 = F97
'Replaced with:
           If Cells(i, 2) = Cells(1, k) Then Cells(j, 6) = Cells(i, 6)
    Next k: Next
```

Therefore, if it seems that the program is doing nothing and could not see any result is either because there are no equal dates in the ranges compared or because results are expected to be shown in the range `J80:CV90` but the values in range `F80:F90` are determining a different output range (i.e. the values in range `F80:F90` are lower than 80 or higher than 90.

I asked for the values in range `F80:F90` to be provided to validate the above.

So if the objective is:

> If the dates are equal, then it takes the value in the same row and column 6 (F) and inserts that value into cells(j, 6)

Then replaced line

```
If Cells(i, 2) = Cells(1, k) Then Cells(j, k) = Cells(j, 6)
```

with line

```
If Cells(i, 2) = Cells(1, k) Then Cells(j, 6) = Cells(i, 6)
```

The value of `j` is the value in `cell(i,6)` as determined by the line:
`j = Cells(i, 6)`

Basically if the date in cell `B80` is found in Range `J1:CV1` then enters `73`, value in cell `F80` or `Cell(i,6)`, into cell `F73` or `Cell(j,6)`.

Comment: I am very confused by "This value is then used to reference a row number and places that row number in the column that contains the same date." and " and for those found equal is updating the corresponding cell in the row determined by the corresponding value in the range F80:F90." 

What I want the program to do is: If the dates are equal, then it takes the value in the same row and column 6 (F) and inserts that value into cells(j, 6)

Comment: i'm sure that the issue is not that there are no equal dates in the ranges compared

Comment: Well I just told you what your program is doing, now that you finally mention what you would like the program to do then I'll update my answer with how to achieve that.

Comment: hey EEM i REALLY appreciate you trying to help me out! I'm also REALLY sorry to say that I mistyped what I want my program to do in the above comment. I want the program to do this: if the dates are equal, then it takes the value in cells(j,6) and sets cells(j,k) equal to that value. I am sure that the logic is correct. I edited my question to include my entire  subroutine, hopefully that clarifies everything. I still have no clue why the macro does nothing when executed...

Comment: You have changed everything now, with the changes posted now you **are introducing new errors**, like these lines `For k = 8 To k = 115`; `For k2 = 8 To k2 = 115` and `For k3 = 8 To k3 = 115` these will never work; the correct form is: `For k = 8 To 115`; `For k2 = 8 To 115` and `For k3 = 8 To 115` but you have also changed the ranges before they were 80 to 90 and 10 to 100 now they are 81 to 95 and 8 to 115. Please change your question to the original data so we can work from there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you got confused because you used single-letter variable names and made a mistake in your code that is not easily identifiable.  To correct the error, change this line:

```
If Cells(i, 2) = Cells(1, k) Then Cells(j, k) = Cells(j, 6)
```

To be this instead:

```
If Cells(i, 2) = Cells(1, k) Then Cells(j, k) = Cells(i, 6)
```

Notice the only difference is that instead of setting it to `Cells(j, 6)` it needs to be set to `Cells(i, 6)`.  This is a common mistake for new programmers, and is the exact reason that using descriptive variable names is good practice.  It will prevent simple errors like this.

Comment: this is not the problem, that was all intentional